# Javascript not fading element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to fade in an object when the page loads. However, the object does not fade in or out (I have tried both). What can be causing my javascript program to not execute this code? Thanks for your help.

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fadeIn1").fadeIn(3000);        
    });
</script>
```

Html(simplified):

```
<p id="fadeIn1" style="display:none">Hello</p>
```

Solution:
 I removed unnecessary script tags and the problem was fixed.

Comment: I tried your code and its working so the problem I can think of is maybe the `script` is loaded first before the body.. so try to put the `script` before the end of `body` tag.

Comment: @ShadowFiend even if the script loads before `<body>`, OP is using the document *ready* handler

Comment: @Phil aw.. yeah i forgot that..

Comment: @ShadowFiend Thanks for your answer! I tried your solution but unfortunately, it did not work either.

Comment: @apaul can you show us more of the markup? so we can trace what's the problem..

Comment: Works fine here ~ http://jsfiddle.net/0rghw9cL/. Can you edit that fiddle if it somehow doesn't match your setup (I've included jQuery 3.2.1 and set the JS to run in the `<head>`)

Comment: @Phil I tried creating a new file (which only included the preceding code) to run my code in and it worked perfectly. Therefore it must be something in my file that stops it from executing properly. Thanks for your help, I will edit the jsfiddle.net/0rghw9cL.

Comment: @Phil I found the problem. There were a bunch of links at the bottom of my files for some a reason. When I removed them, it ran perfectly. I will update my question to include the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When you are fading it out then you cannot use style="display:none". Otherwise it is perfectly working

Comment: It's really unclear what you're saying here. Could you perhaps show an example?

Comment: I said that the code is perfectly fine however if you are fading it out then you cannot use display:none to start with. If the display property is set to none at the beginning then there's no point to fadeOut